# the examples of subspace embedding which are not Oblivious

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces

For the definitions of Oblivious Subspace Embedding, please refer to the 1st page of paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3280v1.pdf.  Then, can any one show the examples of subspace embedding which are not Oblivious?

Comment: Even though arXiv should be stable for a long time and there isn't much risk of link rot, it would be helpful if you included the relevant definition in your question (not least so that potential answerers aren't discouraged by the need to download a .pdf).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example: uniform row sampling. That is, the operator A will select rows in X uniformly at random with replacement.

It can be shown that A is a subspace embedding only if the underlying low-dimensional subspace of X is *incoherent*. While for coherent matrices such an operator provably fails. So A is a subspace embedding only for some subspaces and is not an oblivious subspace embedding.

Such an operator was recently applied and analyzed in the context of dimensionality-reduced subspace clustering in the following paper:
http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v37/wange15.pdf